# In Android, how to place image at center on a button without stretching?

Tags: android, image, button, layout

In a Android layout file, I have a button. And I want to present an image for the button without any text. The problem I have is, the image is stretched to cover the whole button area. Instead of stretching, I'd like to have the button placed at the center of the button without any distortion to the image.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="38dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/icon_more"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Right now, it looks like this:

[image]

It's horizontally stretched, which is not what I want.

Comment: Use an `ImageView`, set it's background and use its onClickListener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ImageButton is another choice for you. You can try:

```
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_more"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        />
```

Flexibly combining attributes layout_width, layout_height and scaleType helps you a good UI

Comment: your suggestion worked for me. I didn't know about ImageButton which was what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="XXdp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/yourimage
        android:text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In some themes, there are some default properties (`minWidth`, `minHeight`...) with `Button`. So that cause your background is stretching. I suggest you use `ImageView` like @ShamasS comment, or if you want to use `Button`, try to add these properties in your `xml`:

```
<Button
...
android:minHeight="0dp"
android:minWidth="0dp"/>
```

or programmatically with `setMinHeight(0)`, `setMinWidth(0)`.

Hope that help!